# Compare two list if match found update first list property

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists first is

```
DataTable DtblDiseaseList = this.GetDisease();
List<DiseaseModel> model = DtblDiseaseList.DataTableToList<DiseaseModel>();
```

And second is

```
var userDisease = DiseaseManagementBA.getUserDisease(UserID).DataTableToList<DiseaseModel>();
```

Here I want to compare userDisease with model list if match found then I want to update the property of first list i.e. `model`. In `DiseaseModel` class there is on property i.e. `IsChecked`. I want to set `true` to this property if match found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello guys my problem is solved by this `Linq` query

```
model.Where(x => userDisease.Any(z => z.DiseaseId == x.DiseaseId)).Select(x => { x.IsChecked = true; return x; }).ToList();
```

Comment: O(n^2) you really should be using a HashSet or something for the key lookup.

Answer (score 0):

The first "if match found" can be done using a Join.  This enumerates each of your lists and returns the results from model in which the "match" condition is found.  I am presuming there the "match" is matching IDs as I don't know the actual criteria.

```
var result = (from m in model
              where join d in userDisease on m.ID == d.ID
              select m).ToList();
```

Once you have the list, its a matter of iterating and setting the value. I'm sort of assuming you're using LinqToSql with the InsertOnSubmit and the SubmitChanges methods.

```
foreach (var r in result)
{
  r.IsChecked = true;
  this.InsertOnSubmit(r);
}     

this.SubmitChanges();
```

I should note that this will work, but results from the first join are enumerated into memory, they are not updated by the database.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My problem is solved. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it simply as following:

```
model.Intersect(userDisease).ToList().ForEach(_ => _.IsChecked = true);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. My problem is solved. See my answer.